# System Partition on wrong drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8

For some reason my secondary hard drive is marked as System in disk management. It is a full drive and I would like to format it. However I keep receiving a message "Cannot delete the active system partition on this disk". The disk has never had windows on it and Windows does not boot from it, so what is going on here?

Another thing I noticed is that C: is marked as "Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Primary Partition" while this drive is marked as "System, Active, Primary Partition". Is there any particular reason for this?

I have been able to format it in the past and as far as I know no settings have been changed. IS there a way I can format the drive?

Comment: Are you sure you were able to format it previously? And if so, have you run Startup Repair or perhaps upgraded to Win8 since then? Do you have access to a Win8 DVD?

Comment: Yes I am positive that I have been able to format it previously. Yes I have upgraded to Winodws 8 since then (clean install). Also, I have access to a Windows 8 Disk

Comment: Alright, then try disconnecting the secondary drive. Quite likely the system will no longer boot, in which case you can boot from the DVD and run Startup Repair. Once that's done see if you're allowed to format the drive. If not, there's always the option of using a Linux LiveCD/USB to format it.